# Navigation Drawer always visible (a little bit)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using the Google's new Navigation Drawer, and i'm trying to set it always visible, like in Hangout,[image: Like this]) but i  can't find any documentation on how to achieve this.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hangouts does **not** use a Navigation Drawer, but instead uses a [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) per the [details on the difference between the Navigation Drawer and SlidingPaneLayout post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AdamWPowell/posts/8j2GVw72i1E) by one of the Android developers.

Comment: So there is no way to achieve this with the Navigation Drawer?

Comment: @Garro88 - per the post I linked "The key difference was that our navigation drawer pattern was independent of screen size; in cases where we wanted a nav drawer we wanted it tucked away until summoned. A larger screen didn’t mean that there was some responsive design inflection point where the drawer became permanently visible." - `SlidingPaneLayout` is appropriate for master/detail type data while the `DrawerLayout` is appropriate for navigation only.

Comment: Many thanks!! After spending a huge while looking for a way using DrawerLayouts, I finally did using this SlidingPaneLayout instead. Didn't know it existed.

Comment: @GuilhermeSantos - it isn't a very common pattern now a days (you won't find it in the [Material Design guidelines](https://material.google.com/) for instance), but it certainly works for what it is there for!